# Lookup and append based on value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to accomplish the following:

**Table 1: Data inputs with names with fruits**

```
Apple  | John | Peter | Chia <br>
Orange | Peter | Lim    <br>
Pear   | Peter | Tan    <br>
Banana | Tan | James    <br>
Kiwi   | Wee        <br>
```

The code will read the above table and generates the following table:

```
John | Apple <br>
Peter | Apple, Orange, Pear <br>
Chia | Apple <br>
Lim | Orange <br>
Tan | Pear, Banana <br>
Jame | Banana <br>
Wee | Kiwi
```

This is to identify some form of resource conflict using excel. Is there any way to do it without vba? If there isn't, is there anyway to do it with loops?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt you can do this using just vanilla-flavored plain Excel.  But maybe pivot tables could do it.  Certainly, you could write a VBA script to handle this.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I tried writing a VBA script to handle this but it results in a very long processing time. Is there any way I can write one without loops?

Comment: Is there any chance you could change your source data, or perhaps inspire the creator the source data to send you a more friendly format?

Comment: I can't. can you help to provide the looped code?

Answer (score 3):

as Tim suggested, it is possible with a simple pivot table (in blue on the right):

[image: resulting Pivottable and Data for it]

The only problem that I see right now, is getting your Input Data into the format that pivot tables need ... the area to the left of the pivot table.

But maybe your source can supply the data in single rows instead?

Kaz

Comment: Thank you. The source can't supply the data in single rows as it will duplicate other information related to the fruits. e.g. weight, sweetness etc.